# Is there an easy fix to use IsOwnerOrReadOnly with `user` instead of `owner` attribute?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-1.7

I'm trying for the first time to build an api with Django REST framework. Now I want to use IsOwnerOrReadOnly, but all my models have `user` fields. Is there a way to tell the IsOwnerOrReadOnly permission to use `user` instead of `owner`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Isn't the IsOwnerOrReadOnly class only an example from django-rest-framework tutorial? You have to write it yourself, so you can just replace:

```
return obj.owner == request.user
```

with

```
return obj.user == request.user
```

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake. I thought that's the actual class. My English is not so good. Thanks very much.